# Flink: Could not find any factory for identifier 'kafka' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.CatalogFactory' in the classpath

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to connect Kafka to Flink and run via `sql-client.sh`. However, no matter what I do with `.yaml` and libraries, I keep getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClientException: Unexpected exception. This is a bug. Please consider filing an issue.
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:201)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.main(SqlClient.java:161)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unable to create catalog 'myKafka'.

Catalog options are:
'type'='kafka'
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createCatalog(FactoryUtil.java:270)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.createCatalog(LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.java:217)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.lambda$initializeCatalogs$1(LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.java:120)
        at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.initializeCatalogs(LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.java:117)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.initializeSessionState(LegacyTableEnvironmentInitializer.java:105)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.SessionContext.create(SessionContext.java:233)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalContextUtils.buildSessionContext(LocalContextUtils.java:100)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.openSession(LocalExecutor.java:91)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.start(SqlClient.java:88)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:187)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factory for identifier 'kafka' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.CatalogFactory' in the classpath.

Available factory identifiers are:

generic_in_memory
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.discoverFactory(FactoryUtil.java:319)
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.getCatalogFactory(FactoryUtil.java:455)
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createCatalog(FactoryUtil.java:251)
        ... 11 more
```

My sql-conf is pretty simple (I didn't include sensitive information such as bootstrap servers):

```
catalogs:
 - name: myKafka
   type: kafka
```

In addition, the `library` folder includes the following jars:

- `flink-avro-confluent-registry-1.13.2.jar`
- `flink-connector-kafka_2.12-1.13.2.jar`
- `flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.12-1.13.2.jar`
- `kafka-clients-2.0.0-cdh6.1.1.jar`

The Flink version: `1.13.2`. The Kafka version: `2.0.0-cdh6.1.1`.

**Solution** (thanks to @Niko for pointing me in the right direction):
I modified the `sql-conf.yaml` to use `hive` catalog and created Kafka table inside of the SQL. So, my `sql-conf.yaml` looks like:

```
execution:
  type: streaming
  result-mode: table
  planner: blink
  current-database: default
  current-catalog: myhive

catalogs:
  - name: myhive
    type: hive
    hive-version: 2.1.1-cdh6.0.1
    hive-conf-dir: /etc/hive/conf
  
deployment:
  m: yarn-cluster
  yqu: ABC_XYZ
```

ran it and inside of SQL-client.sh, created Kafka table using necessary connections.

Comment: In your case, I think you should not config catalogs type as kafka, all you need  is creating a source table with connector type set to kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All catalogs defined using YAML must provide a type property that specifies the type of catalog. The following types are supported out of the box:

- generic_in_memory
- hive

You can read more about in [official doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/catalogs/)

You can create your so-called [*initialization SQL file*](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sqlclient/#initialize-session-using-sql-files) like:

```
CREATE CATALOG MyCatalog WITH (
    'type' = 'hive',
    'default-database' = 'my_database',
    'hive-conf-dir' = '/etc/hive/conf'
  );

USE CATALOG MyCatalog;

CREATE TABLE MyTable(
  MyField1 INT,
  MyField2 STRING
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'YOUR_TOPIC',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost',
  'properties.group.id' = 'some_id',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
  'format' = 'json'
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I avoided the init file all together but regardless, it worked.